# How can I improve accuracy when using Google Speech-to-Text API version v1?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, google-speech-to-text-api

I'm currently working on integrating the Google Speech-to-Text API v1 into my application for audio transcription. While the API generally provides decent results, I'm looking for ways to improve the accuracy of the transcriptions, especially for challenging audio recordings.

```
    RecognitionConfig config = RecognitionConfig.newBuilder()
                .setEncoding(RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.ENCODING_UNSPECIFIED)
                .setSampleRateHertz(sampleRate)
                .setAudioChannelCount(channelCount)
                .setLanguageCode("en-US").build();
```

This is my RecognitionConfig configuration.

I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions on techniques or configurations that can help me achieve better results with the API.

Comment: What's the definition of "challenging audio recordings"? I presume Google already applies noise removal to the audio and feeds raw transcriptions through a language model. Other than supplying cleaner audio or trying different engines (namely Whisper) there is no way. I'll stick around and see if I'm wrong.

Comment: Audio link file :

https://storage.googleapis.com/sharedpro_gogole_bucket/audio/audio-file.wav                       
                                                                                                                                                                                       response: hello my name is renisha and working as a software quality assurance in turn in shedrow technology from past one month.

Comment: @doneforaiur  Audio link file : storage.googleapis.com/sharedpro_gogole_bucket/audio/… response: hello my name is renisha and working as a software quality assurance in turn in shedrow technology from past one month.

Comment: You can try Whisper here; https://huggingface.co/spaces/whisper-event/whisper-demo . The output for your audio was; " Hello, my name is Vanesha. I am working as a software quality assurance intern in Shared Pro Technologies from past one month.". There might be models finetuned on Indian accent but you'd have to host them yourself.